# after homestead provision it delete custom nginx settings in sites-available

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I am using homestead with my vagrantbox.
After I vagrant provision, I notice that my nginx sites-available file has been reset. I have to copy and paste again and restart my nginx server.

Any solution it will save it first and copy itself? or in config file can do some setting?

Comment: here you can read how to use a custom homestead config: https://medium.com/@maxxscho/laravel-homestead-with-custom-nginx-configurations-2e0fda4ba7dc

Comment: Here is collected some ways to resolve it - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/homestead-provision-deletes-custom-nginx-settings